# Content height changed on click JS events triggering

Tags: javascript, css

Here I add the expected layout and [codepen](https://codepen.io/momin-ctg/pen/ZZPgwv) repository
[image]

and here is my front end code

```css
.mgh-std-com-area {
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem:hover {
  background: #EEF9F9;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem:hover>.mgh-sc-box {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem .mgh-sc-box {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #EEF9F9;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem .mgh-sc-box img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem h5 {
  color: #2F2F2F;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: calc(22px + (30 - 22) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem h5::after {
  content: '';
  width: 80px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #349DCD;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  font-size: calc(16px + (22 - 16) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}

.mgh-btn {
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #50C1C4, #349DCD);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .9em 1em;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.mgh-btn:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #50C1C4, #349DCD);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="mgh-common-header text-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0">
    <h2>Standards & Compliances</h2>
    <p>Maintaining the highest of standards while conforming to regulations</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mgh-std-com">
    <div class="row text-center justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0">
        <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

          <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
            <img src="assets/images/std-one.svg" alt="">
          </div>

          <h5>
            At MGH Healthcare, quality is a shared responsibility
          </h5>

          <p>Quality is the core value of MGH Healthcare that it ensures to be implemented at all levels. ADS’s management will ensure that this policy and relevant all legal and regulatory requirements are effectively communicated to the employees and other
            concerned personnel of quality assurance and operations to uphold company’s high standards of quality compliance at all times.</p>

          <a href="" class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto pt-5 pt-xl-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="1000">
        <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

          <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
            <img src="assets/images/std-two.svg" alt="">
          </div>

          <h5>
            Putting safety of products, customers and employees as
          </h5>

          <p>As a responsible business organization, MGH Healthcare operates its business according to the directives and guidelines of GxP, HSE and other local regulatory authorities. MGH Healthcare has stringent mandatory quality standards which ensure
            quality and safety of its products which conform to the relevant industry and regulatory standards.</p>

          <a href="" class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto pt-5 pt-xl-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="2000">
        <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

          <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
            <img src="assets/images/std-three.svg" alt="">
          </div>

          <h5>
            Building and maintaining a system to ensure quality and safety at all levels.
          </h5>

          <p>MGH Healthcare maintains a management system, which proactively and continuously develop its processes and systems to ensure quality and safety throughout the whole chain by providing training and resources. MGH Healthcare regularly evaluates
            and improves its performances using both internal and external measures.
          </p>

          <a href="" class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to need, when click on button height will be changed and text will be extend with some css transitions effects! example screenshot has been added.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this,

Try to manipulate css of text-matter class and adjust height according to your need, this class is to hide the extra text matter and when a button is clicked full text will be shown.

Check this [Pen](https://codepen.io/shoyebsheikh/pen/KLPepO/)

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("mgh-btn");
  var font_to_incr_by = 2;
  var sibling;
  var myFunction = function() {
    sibling = this.previousElementSibling;
    this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('text-matter');
    this.previousElementSibling.classList.add('text-matter-rev');
    var font_h5 = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(sibling.previousElementSibling, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
    sibling.previousElementSibling.style.fontSize = (font_h5 + font_to_incr_by) + 'px';
    var font_p = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(sibling, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
    sibling.style.fontSize = (font_p + font_to_incr_by) + 'px';
    this.closest(".mgh-std-com-sitem").classList.add("border-blue");
    this.closest(".mgh-std-com-sitem").style.padding='0';
    for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
      if (classname[i].previousElementSibling != this.previousElementSibling) {
        let sibling = classname[i].previousElementSibling;
        classname[i].previousElementSibling.classList.add('text-matter');
        classname[i].previousElementSibling.classList.remove('text-matter-rev');
        classname[i].closest(".mgh-std-com-sitem").classList.remove("border-blue");
        sibling.previousElementSibling.style.fontSize = font_h5 + 'px';
        sibling.style.fontSize = font_p + 'px';
        classname[i].closest(".mgh-std-com-sitem").style.padding='50px';
      }
    }
  };

  var myFunction2 = function() {
    sibling == this ? this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('clicked') : this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('clicked');
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    classname[i].previousElementSibling.addEventListener('transitionend', myFunction2, false);
  }
```

```css
.mgh-std-com-area {
    margin: 80px 0;
  }

  .mgh-std-com-sitem {
    /* transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; */
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    height: 600px
  }

  .mgh-std-com-sitem:hover {
    background: #EEF9F9;
  }

  .mgh-std-com-sitem:hover>.mgh-sc-box {
    background: #ffffff;
  }

  .mgh-std-com-sitem .mgh-sc-box {
    /* transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #EEF9F9;
  }

  .mgh-std-com-sitem .mgh-sc-box img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .mgh-std-com-sitem h5 {
    color: #2F2F2F;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: calc(22px + (30 - 22) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
  }

  .mgh-std-com-sitem h5::after {
    content: '';
    width: 80px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #349DCD;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  .mgh-std-com-sitem p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-size: calc(16px + (22 - 16) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
  }

  .mgh-btn {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #50C1C4, #349DCD);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .9em 1em;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 180px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .mgh-btn:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #50C1C4, #349DCD);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .text-matter {
    max-height: 125px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all linear 1s;
  }

  .text-matter-rev {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: all linear 1s;
  }

  .clicked {
    display: none;
  }

  .border-blue {
    border: 2px solid #84c9f3 !important;
  }
  .mgh-std-com{
    height: 600px
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="mgh-common-header text-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic"
         data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0">
      <h2>Standards & Compliances</h2>
      <p>Maintaining the highest of standards while conforming to regulations</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mgh-std-com">
      <div class="row text-center justify-content-sm-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto" data-aos="fade-up"
             data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0">
          <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

            <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
              <img src="assets/images/std-one.svg" alt="">
            </div>

            <h5>
              At MGH Healthcare, quality is a shared responsibility
            </h5>

            <p class="text-matter">Quality is the core value of MGH Healthcare that it ensures to be implemented at all levels. ADS’s
              management will ensure that this policy and relevant all legal and regulatory requirements are effectively
              communicated to the employees and other concerned personnel of quality assurance and operations to uphold
              company’s high standards of
              quality compliance at all times.</p>

            <a class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto pt-5 pt-xl-0" data-aos="fade-up"
             data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="1000">
          <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

            <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
              <img src="assets/images/std-two.svg" alt="">
            </div>

            <h5>
              Putting safety of products, customers and employees as
            </h5>

            <p class="text-matter">As a responsible business organization, MGH Healthcare operates its business according to the directives
              and guidelines of GxP, HSE and other local regulatory authorities. MGH Healthcare has stringent mandatory
              quality standards which ensure quality and safety of its products which conform to the relevant industry
              and regulatory standards.</p>

            <a class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto pt-5 pt-xl-0" data-aos="fade-up"
             data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="2000">
          <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

            <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
              <img src="assets/images/std-three.svg" alt="">
            </div>

            <h5>
              Building and maintaining a system to ensure quality and safety at all levels.
            </h5>

            <p class="text-matter">MGH Healthcare maintains a management system, which proactively and continuously develop its processes
              and systems to ensure quality and safety throughout the whole chain by providing training and resources.
              MGH Healthcare regularly evaluates and improves its performances using both internal and external
              measures.</p>

            <a class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you can do this with vanilla JavaScript .

Comment: Thanks ! I have to need a little bit animation or transition on click event when i click on button, background color and text will expanding with some animations .

Comment: animation can be developed by `opacity:0` to `opacity: 1` and `visibility: hidden` to visibility: visible`

Comment: actually text expand transition will be work like this
https://codepen.io/momin-ctg/pen/XwWMWy

Comment: you are almost done, just smoothness on text expand and background color animation needed on click event !

Comment: @Momin we dont work for you, we just here to help, hire a developer for your work

Comment: Your helps are highly appreciate ! But I have to need background color and text extending animations...

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla javascript you do something like this:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mgh-std-com-sitem');
elements.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!el.classList.contains('transition-class-name')) {
      el.classList.add('transition-class-name');
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('transition-class-name');
    }
  });
});
```

This would add the `transition-class-name` to the element on click if it is not there already. If the element has the class - it will remove it. Essentially it will toggle the element on click.

EDIT: Here is a revised pen to illustrate the usage: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNNLBe

Note that you might need to update your CSS/selectors for it to do exactly what you might want.

Comment: Could you update on codepen or above link, I have shared ?

Comment: I have to need on click button will disappear and text will expand

Comment: Then update the `document.querySelectorAll('.mgh-std-com-sitem`)` with the appropriate button css selector.

Comment: Okay ! If you look the picture, when I click on button, `background-color` will appear  and button itself will disappear and at the same time text will expand and height also...................